# EmberJS not rendering my template

Tags: ember.js

I am using external templates

```
Ember.TEMPLATES["application"] = Handlebars.template(function (Handlebars,depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
  this.compilerInfo = [2,'>= 1.0.0-rc.3'];
helpers = helpers || Handlebars.helpers; data = data || {};
  var stack1, functionType="function", escapeExpression=this.escapeExpression;


  if (stack1 = helpers.outlet) { stack1 = stack1.call(depth0, {hash:{},data:data}); }
  else { stack1 = depth0.outlet; stack1 = typeof stack1 === functionType ? stack1.apply(depth0) : stack1; }
  return escapeExpression(stack1);
  });

Ember.TEMPLATES["teams"] = Handlebars.template(function (Handlebars,depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
  this.compilerInfo = [2,'>= 1.0.0-rc.3'];
helpers = helpers || Handlebars.helpers; data = data || {};
  var buffer = "", stack1, options, helperMissing=helpers.helperMissing, escapeExpression=this.escapeExpression;


  buffer += "<div class=\"container-fluid hero team-banner\"><i class=\"icon-cheer\"></i><h1>Fan a Team</h1><span>Choose one or more teams from the list below to get started.</span></div><div class=\"container\"><div class=\"row-fluid team-tab\"><ul class=\"row-fluid nav nav-tabs\"><li class=\"active\"><a>3A</a></li><li><a>2A</a></li><li><a>1A</a></li><li class=\"title\">Conference:</li></ul></div><div class=\"tab-content\"><div class=\"row-fluid tab-pane active\"><div class=\"row-fluid division\"><div class=\"row-fluid division-header\">";
  options = {hash:{},data:data};
  buffer += escapeExpression(((stack1 = helpers.Team),stack1 ? stack1.call(depth0, depth0.Name, options) : helperMissing.call(depth0, "Team", depth0.Name, options)))
    + "</div><div class=\"row-fluid division-content\"><table class=\"table table-bordered\"><tr><td class=\"team-logo\"><div class=\"img-wrapper\"></div></td><td class=\"name\">Golden St. Elites, Golden Eagles</td><td class=\"location\">San Mateo, CA</td><td class=\"options\"></td></tr><tr><td class=\"team-logo\"><div class=\"img-wrapper\"></div></td><td class=\"name\">Golden St. Elites, Golden Eagles</td><td class=\"location\">San Mateo, CA</td><td class=\"options\"><input /></td></tr><tr><td class=\"team-logo\"><div class=\"img-wrapper\"></div></td><td class=\"name\">Golden St. Elites, Golden Eagles</td><td class=\"location\">San Mateo, CA</td><td class=\"options\"><input /></td></tr><tr><td class=\"team-logo\"><div class=\"img-wrapper\"></div></td><td class=\"name\">Golden St. Elites, Golden Eagles</td><td class=\"location\">San Mateo, CA</td><td class=\"options\"><input /></td></tr></table></div></div></div><div class=\"text-centered\"><a class=\"btn btn-large btn-success\">Start Spinning</a></div></div></div>";
  return buffer;
  });
```

which i can confirm are loaded and not throwing errors.

Then I have my application controller and teams controller both of which are loaded and not throwing errors.

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend();


App.TeamsController = Ember.Controller.extend
  content: []
```

then I have my views which are loaded and not throwing errors and relate to the templates

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: "application"
});


App.TeamsView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: "teams"
});
```

lastly i have a router

```
   App.Router.map ->
     this.route('teams', {path: '/'})
```

I am confused as to how it even knows where to stick the outlet from the external template.

also I don't know if it matters to the router but the page is at '/teams.html' not '/'

if anyone can help, id appreciate it i just need to know how to get this started, right now I am seeing no signs of life.

If the syntax looks off i've been slowly converting some things to coffeescript.

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.1
DEBUG: Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.3
DEBUG: jQuery.VERSION : 1.9.1 
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

Comment: Which version of Ember are you using? You seem to use a current Handlebars version, but you are using an outdated Router API.

Comment: is it an issue that this is being executed in '/teams.html' rather than '/'

Comment: No you are using an outdated router API. You are probably building upon an outdated tutorial. You need to adapt your router. Have a look at the following tutorial for a nice introduction: http://twbrandt.github.com/2013/02/11/Ember-Quick_Start_Guide/

Comment: Ok thats helpful for sure, so i have to have somehting called IndexController i can't use TeamsController instead?

Comment: You have an IndexController, but you can also use TeamController. I can't see what your app is about, but i am sure you will need a TeamsRoute. This route will be automatically associated with your TeamsController.

Comment: Have a look at the example. The contributors route in the example should be a very good template for your TeamsRoute.

Comment: right so can i use 'App.Router.map ->
  this.route('teams', {path: '/'})' to make it the index path?

Comment: Yeah, this should work.

Comment: well my application template is rendering now so small success but my teams template is not rendering in the outlet.