# Emberjs template is not displaying

Tags: ember.js

I've solved a couple router issues by updating the syntax

I have the following for a router

```
App.Router.map ->
  this.route('teams', {path: '/'})
```

The application template does render

but inside it is an outlet which is not getting the teams template

```
Ember.TEMPLATES["teams"] = Handlebars.template(function (Handlebars,depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
  this.compilerInfo = [2,'>= 1.0.0-rc.3'];
helpers = helpers || Handlebars.helpers; data = data || {};



  return "<h1>I AM A TEST</h1>";
  });
```

given my router that template should be rendered correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774203/emberjs-not-rendering-my-template

Comment: this is a different question, so i opened a new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, given that router and assuming there is an `{{outlet}}` in your application template the teams template should render.

I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VBT9H/) based on your code, there you can see the teams template rendering properly.

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.Router.map(function() {
  return this.route('teams', {path: '/'});
});

Ember.TEMPLATES["application"] = Ember.Handlebars.compile("<h1>APP TEMPLATE</h1><hr/>{{outlet}}");

Ember.TEMPLATES["teams"] = Handlebars.template(function (Handlebars,depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
  this.compilerInfo = [2,'>= 1.0.0-rc.3'];
  helpers = helpers || Handlebars.helpers; data = data || {};
  return "<h1>I AM A TEST</h1>";
});
```

Had to guess about what's in the application template.

Comment: i figured it out.. shame on me for being a newb. I was compiling my template wrong and using Handlebars.compile rather than Ember.Handlebars